# Add values in two dictionaries together on same key

Tags: python

How can I approach adding items from two table-indexed dictionaries together as in this simple example?

```
table1 = {'item1': {'quantity': 3, 'value': 3.0}, \
          'item2': {'quantity': 10, 'value': 30} \
          }

table2 = {'item1': {'quantity': 5, 'value': 5.0}, \
          'item3': {'quantity': 7, 'value': 10.5} \
          }

newDic = {'item1': {'quantity': 8, 'value': 8.0}, \
          'item2': {'quantity': 10, 'value': 30}, \
          'item3': {'quantity': 7, 'value': 10.5} \
          }
```

I have a function that parses and filters contents of a flat file into a dictionary. I'd like to redesign the script to parse multiple files. Each table has exactly the same column headers. The rows have same items with different values, but some files have *additional* items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `table2` to `table1`

```
table1 = {'item1': {'quantity': 3, 'value': 3.0}, \
          'item2': {'quantity': 10, 'value': 30} \
          }

table2 = {'item1': {'quantity': 5, 'value': 5.0}, \
          'item3': {'quantity': 7, 'value': 10.5} \
          }

for key, val in table2.items():
   if key not in table1:
       table1[key] = val
   else:
       for k, v in val.items():
           if k not in table1[key]:
               table1[key][k] = v
           else:
               table1[key][k] += v

print table1
```

.

```
{
  'item2': {'value': 30, 'quantity': 10}, 
  'item3': {'value': 10.5, 'quantity': 7}, 
  'item1': {'value': 8.0, 'quantity': 8}
}
```

Comment: Super-fast. Add t2 to t1. Sounds good. I could also add to a new table t1 and t2. Which way--was set'n me to loops. Thanks!

Comment: what about if the depth changes ?

Comment: @sjcipher I posted this in part because I was distracted by the possible solutions I would need. When should one spend the time to learn a third party table module--is the question...